# Warning CertificateServicesClient-AutoEnrollment in event Viewer

Tags: windows, certificate

I have a warning in the Windows Event Viewer that tell me some certificate is going to be expired.  I'm a little worried about what 's going on.
this is the message in event viewer :

> Certificate for local system with Thumbprint b9 38 e7 e7 40 29 6c 59
> ba eb 94 b7 77 a6 95 16 5c 90 a4 32 is about to expire or already
> expired.

Event ID : 64

Any idea would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following PowerShell commands to return details about the expiring certificate:

```
# copy-paste here the cert thumbprint from Event Viewer
$Thumbprint = "b9 38 e7 e7 40 29 6c 59 ba eb 94 b7 77 a6 95 16 5c 90 a4 32"
$Thumbprint = $Thumbprint.Replace(" ","") # removing extra spaces
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser,Cert:\LocalMachine -Recurse | `
  Where-Object -Property Thumbprint -Like $Thumbprint | `
  Select-Object -Property *
```

And if you want to to remove it because it's expired, then here are the removal commands:

```
$Thumbprint = "b9 38 e7 e7 40 29 6c 59 ba eb 94 b7 77 a6 95 16 5c 90 a4 32"
$Thumbprint = $Thumbprint.Replace(" ","") # removing extra spaces
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser,Cert:\LocalMachine -Recurse | `
  Where-Object -Property Thumbprint -Like $Thumbprint | `
  Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me as well. I tried to renew mine, called Microsoft and they told me to remove it and do an update, which I did.

Here are my saved instructions on how to remove a cert. Do a system save before you remove the cert.

1- Click Start, type mmc, and then press ENTER.
2- If the User Account Control dialog box appears, confirm that the action it displays is what you want, and then click Continue.
3- On the File menu, click Add/Remove Snap-in, click Certificates, and then click Add.
4- Select the user or computer account that logged the error, and click Next.
5- Click Finish, and then click OK.
6- In the console tree, click Certificates - Current User or Certificates (Local Computer), and then click Personal.
7- In the console tree, double-click Certificates, double-click Personal, and then click Certificates.
8- Locate the certificate with the thumbprint listed in the event log message.
9 - Right-click the certificate, and select Delete